# Gmaps4Rails and Richmarker Changing Marker Anchor Changes Nothing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

While using Rich Marker and setting different offsets inside

```
:marker_anchor=>[ ANY_INTEGER,true]
```

nothing changes. Have no idea what to do?
Tried to make an offset with css but RichMarker creates a blank div container for my content by default, so making offset for an inside html lives a blank div. so when i click on a map where i don see a marker (but there is a parent div) my infobox pops up?

I`m totally frustrated.

Now it works! It accepts int numbers

```
from 1 to 9
```

that represents nine possible positions of a block 1 is top-right, 2-top middle, 3 - top left... ... 5- center etc

Comment: I'll look at it soon: I've finished the conversion to coffeescript. What slows me down is the lack of testing mocks for google maps. Whatever, no reason for frustration :)

Comment: Hope so *) M`be you know how to style parent div? the one was created by richmarker and has no id or class?

Comment: Just a thought: since you know the class of your rich markers, you could grab the parent id using jQuery selectors and style it the way you need

Comment: ...not the parent id, the parent itself...

Comment: Seen a bug in 1.1.0 and just fixed it but no error concerning offset. I just tried and it works properly. Get the code from github until 1.1.1 is released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated gem does the trick. Thanks for reporting :)

Comment: Just changed the version in GemFile and loaded new one - and map disappeared. I can see it in JS console with markers. But nothing appears on the screen

Comment: What??? You're now using 1.1.3 or 1.1.4? Any js error? Could you paste relevant gmaps call in a gist?

Comment: Feel free to contact me via github. I receive mails which makes worflow faster. I can't believe there is a bug in the latest version.